# Data manipulation of two list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following two lists:

```
retrieved_sessions = [
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T08:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '5'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T09:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '7'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T10:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '6'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T11:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '5'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T12:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '0'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T13:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '2'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T14:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '13'}
]
```

```
all_sessions = [
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T09:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T09:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T10:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T10:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T11:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T11:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T12:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T12:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T13:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T13:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T14:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T14:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T15:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T15:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}
]
```

I was wondering, what would be the best way to update the dictionary in `all_sessions` with the `availability` from the corresponding `retrieved_sessions` dictinary, using the `start_time` as the primary key lookup/matching field?

Expected output:

```
all_sessions = [
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T09:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T09:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '7'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T10:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T10:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '6'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T11:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T11:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '5'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T12:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T12:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '0'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T13:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T13:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '2'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T14:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T14:30:00.000Z', 'availability': '13'}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T15:00:00.000Z', 'availability': None}, 
    {'start_time': '2020-01-17T15:30:00.000Z', 'availability': None}
]
```

I have tried the following loop within a loop:

```
for available in availability:
    for session in sessions:
        if session['start_time'] == available['start_time']:
            session['availability'] = available['availability']
```

N.B. Data is coming from a SOAP API, hence the wierd `'1'`/`'2'` instead of e.g., `1`, `2`.  etc

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.isin`

Comment: It might be worth using something like a Pandas DataFrame, handling this kind of data in a bunch of dictionaries is going to get annoying.

Comment: This works perfectly if you replace the variables in your code with the names of the actual dictionaries. With `for available in retrieved_sessions:
    for session in all_sessions:` I get your output exactly. Is that a valid solution, or are you searching for something more optimized?

Comment: The path of least resistance seems to be updating your `retrieved_sessions` dict to be keyed from the start time vale to the availability value (e.g.: `{'2020-01-17T15:30:00.000Z': None}`. And then you can call this dict as a lookup for each dict in `all_sessions`

Comment: @BrianJoseph I need the key <=> value pairs as I am sending it down as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make helper dict where the key is `start_time` and value is `availability` and then replace correspondent values in `all_sessions`

```
d = {s['start_time']: s['availability'] for s in retrieved_sessions}

for s in all_sessions:
    s['availability'] = d.get(s['start_time'])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(all_sessions)
```

Prints:

```
[{'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T09:00:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': '7', 'start_time': '2020-01-17T09:30:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T10:00:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': '6', 'start_time': '2020-01-17T10:30:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T11:00:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': '5', 'start_time': '2020-01-17T11:30:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T12:00:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': '0', 'start_time': '2020-01-17T12:30:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T13:00:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': '2', 'start_time': '2020-01-17T13:30:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T14:00:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': '13', 'start_time': '2020-01-17T14:30:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T15:00:00.000Z'},
 {'availability': None, 'start_time': '2020-01-17T15:30:00.000Z'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dict with start_time as keys and availability as values.

Then iterate over copy.deepcopy(all_sessions).items(), matching on start_time and adding to the original all_sessions as you go.  The deepcopy is because you can't iterate over a dict and modify it in the same pass.

The two nested for loops in your example are O(n*m) - IOW it's slow.  Introducing a dict this way will speed things up to O(n+m).

Note that keying on times is prone to problems from duplicate times.